# How can I decode a quotedprintable encoded String?

Tags: haskell, decode

I'm writing a webmail app and need to decode Quotedprintable values in the emails header fields.

I've tried several decode functions from various packages on haskell, so far without luck.

How can I decode for example this string:

```
"freelancermap Newsletter:  Erfolgreich =?ISO-8859-1?Q?selbstst=E4ndig?= mit Sicherheit"
```

Comment: This is actually not "quoted-printable", but "encoded-word" encoding. The [darcs source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/darcs-beta/2.7.98.1/doc/html/src/Darcs-Email.html) contains some utility functions for encoding and decoding these types of strings. I don't think there is good library support for this.

Comment: For anyone finding this near present day, it has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985012/how-can-i-decode-an-encoded-word-string/38999303#38999303