# How can I decode an encoded-word String?

Tags: haskell

Note that this question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098452/how-can-i-decode-a-quotedprintable-encoded-string) previously unanswered question.
It is also the same as [this PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468849/iso-8859-1-in-mail-subject), but I'm looking for the haskell equivalent.

[RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) defines the standard for "encoded-word" encodings and provides an example of:

```
=?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
```

Is there a standard haskell library for dealing with decoding this into it's correct `Text` representation?

This shouldn't be too hard to write a custom parser using parsec and the RFC Spec, but this seems like a common, solved problem in other languages that I cannot find a Haskell equivalent for, and I'd rather not re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Have a look at the [mime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime) package.

Comment: @ErikR Unless there is something I'm missing there, it doesn't handle this type of encoding. Codec.MIME.Decode explicitly states "Currently, base64 and quoted-printable are the only two encodings supported.". So it would turn my example into "=?iso-8859-1?q?this is some text?=" instead of "this is some text". That's definitely workable, but then you have to strip extra characters. Also it leaves "_" alone, which is a valid encoded-word representation for " "

Comment: Have a look at code for [decodeWord](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.4.0.2/docs/src/Codec-MIME-Decode.html#decodeWord). Despite the lack of docs, it appears there is support for iso-8859-1.

Comment: @ErikR Oh great that is exactly what I needed thank you! If you want to write up a brief answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`mime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime) package have  look at [`decodeWord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.4.0.2/docs/src/Codec-MIME-Decode.html#decodeWord) in the module [`Codec.MIME.Decode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.4.0.2/docs/Codec-MIME-Decode.html):

```
ghci> import Codec.MIME.Decode
ghci> decodeWord "=?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?="
Just ("this is some text","")
```

From reading the source code both `iso-8859-1` and `us-ascii` are supported.

There is also the `decodeWords` which uses the `decodeWord` function to translate a entire String:

```
ghci> decodeWords "Foo=?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=Bar"
"Foothis is some textBar"
```